# NGX-charts bubble chart how to reload displayed data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I have a bubble chart (using it as a scatter plot but whatever) from ngx-charts. The HTML is set up so that as the user clicks on an element of the page the contents of the chart change based on the `updateTitleData()` function. In testing however as I click on the elements the data of the `scatterData` array changes however this does not change the actual displayed chart. So my question is how to get the chart to dynamically reload while running.

I have read a bit about it online, people have said that you need to change the actual `scatterData` array rather than just the `"series"` element of it which I tried by making an array value in `updateTitleData` that held the whole array and then jut doing `this.scatterData=newData;` at the end of the function which again did set the data correctly but still didn't cause the chart to update.

I also read that you need to put a `[update$]="update$"` in the html code and then when defining the chart variables in the typescript code use `update$: Subject<any> = new Subject();` followed by defining the function `updateChart(){ this.update$.next(true); }` so that you can just call `updateChart()` whenever you need the chart to update. I tried that however it would just throw an error while loading initially due to the `[update$]="update$"` element being included in its constructor.

```
public scatterData = [{
     "name" : "LQArray",
     "series" : [{
         "name" : "a",
         "x" : 1,
         "y" : 2,
         "r" : 1
     }]
 }];

 private updateTitleData() {    
     if(this.regionData && this.regionData.location_quotient){
         this.scatterData["series"] = [];
         this.jobTitles.forEach((value) => {
             var newScatterData = [{
                 "name":value,
                 "x":parseFloat(this.regionData.x_axis[value]),
                 "y":parseInt(this.regionData.y_axis[value]),
                 "r":1
             }];
                  this.scatterData["series"].push(newScatterData);
         });
     }
}
```

Here is the code in question. The chart does display the `"a"` element that is defined at the beginning, but that should be deleted and replaced as soon as the element is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
I was populating the "series" element incorrectly.

What I had:

```
this.jobTitles.forEach((value) => {
     var newScatterData = [{
        "name":value                 
        "x":parseFloat(this.regionData.x_axis[value]),
        "y":parseInt(this.regionData.y_axis[value]),
        "r":1
    }];
         this.scatterData["series"].push(newScatterData);
});
```

What I needed:

```
this.jobTitles.forEach((value) => {
     var newScatterData = {
        "name":value                 
        "x":parseFloat(this.regionData.x_axis[value]),
        "y":parseInt(this.regionData.y_axis[value]),
        "r":1
    };
         this.scatterData[0]["series"].push(newScatterData);
});
this.scatterData=[...this.scatterData];
```

Basically needed the `[0]` in front of the `["series"]` and needed to remove the array element from newScatterData.